# Is it feasible to create wrappers around external code in Spring to track metrics on their run time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

My specific problem relates to Spring Actuator's default health checks - it's not code I have edit access to so I'm not able to wire in Micrometer, but is there still a way to create metrics around them?

Examples of default health checks:

[image]

Comment: You should be able to do what you want using full AspectJ instead of just Spring AOP. But in order to write a specific answer, you need to provide way more information than one general question and a screenshot. Please provide a small sample project - called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please read that article - illustrating your problem and also tell us what you tried so far. No code = no answer.

Comment: i figured it out @kriegaex thanks

Comment: If you figured it out, first of all congratulations.  In order to close the question, please write a comprehensive answer which later you can self-accept. If that is too much work, feel free to delete your question. Just don't leave it open like this.